# What is the meaning of two letter initials written after name initials at the end of a letter. E.g.: Warren Buffett ends a letter with WEB/gk

Tags: letter-writing

I have often been puzzled by this and I have tried to search for an explanation using various keywords on Google but unable to get a proper explanation for this.

Here's an example letter where Warren E. Buffett ends the letter (on the last page) [1](https://www.gurpreetsaluja.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/warren-buffett-1982-derivatives.pdf) with `WEB/gk` - What does `gk` mean in this? I have also seen this in several letters written by Charlie Munger (I think I came across some in Poor Charlie's Almanack)

The closest I was able to come across through some google search was post-nominals but upon reading up on that, I came to realise these are not post-nominals.

Comment: I'd assume that they were the initials of the assistant who was responsible for preparing the letter.

Comment: Per @KillingTime, this is standard shorthand for "Buffet wrote and authorized everything here, but technically GK stenoed/typed/proofread/printed/emailed it."